# Singleton database class method

Tags: php, mysqli, singleton

I'm trying to write a query() method for a singleton database class. I have this but it ain't flying just yet and was looking for some inspiration.

```
<?php
class Database
{
 static private $instance = null;
 protected $mysqli;

 static public function getInstance()
 {
     if (null === self::$instance) {
         self::$instance = new self;
     }
     return self::$instance;
 }

 private function __construct(){
        if(!$this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','db'))
            throw new Exception('Error - Database connection');
 }

 public function query($query) {
    while ($this->mysqli->query($query))
    {
        $row = $this->mysqli->fetch_assoc();
    }
    return $row; // loop through array
 }

 private function __clone(){}

}
?>
```

I'm not entirely sure if I'm going down the correct road. Will mysqli work in this context?
For instance the Mysqli class already has a query() method as part of its class. I'm introducing namespace clashes here?

My query method would handle any sort of SQL statement ie.

Example client code:

```
$DB = Database::getInstance();
$DB->query("SELECT * FROM t");
$DB->query("DELETE FROM t WHERE id=2");
$DB->query("UPDATE u SET col = 'random' WHERE id=4");
```

Comment: I would say you are going down the wrong road. Take a look into prepared statements, mysqli has this but is complicated to wrap in a DB Class. PDO is another viable option which is a bit easier to wrap up. Searching for PDO Wrapper on SO will get you a few options. I would stick to prepared statements as the risk of SQL Injection is significantly lower when handled properly.

Comment: why it will have a issue to write a query method in your class.because you are creating object only in this class. you are not inheriting mysqli class into your. then there will be a issue of method overriding. check  method overridng and overloading in php